# jscolor in a generated form after a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jscolor

I want to use a jscolor for color input http://jscolor.com/, but i cannot use the plugin in a javascript generated form while clicking a button, if i need:

```
//this works
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscolor.js"></script>
<input id="theinput" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#theinput').addClass('jscolor');
});
```

but this doesn't work:

```
<input id="theinput" />
<button id="thebutton">Add Color Propety</button>
```

Javascript..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thebutton').click(function() {
        $('#theinput').addClass('jscolor');
    });
});
```

Comment: have you included the js files for jsColor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick review of the jscolor JS file, you need to call `jscolor` function if you want to dynamically append the color picker to an element :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.thebutton').on('click', function(){
  var myColor = new jscolor($('#theinput')[0]);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="theinput" />
<button class="thebutton">Add Color Propety</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, H4ris!